# MySQL - Difference Between First and Last Record in Group

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `updates` which has the `distance` of a vehicle at the `captured_at` date. Using MySQL, How can I get the SUM of differences between the first captured update and the latest captured update per vehicle.

`updates` table:

```
id | vehicle_id | distance | captured_at
1  | 1          | 100      | 2018-02-10
2  | 1          | 50       | 2018-02-05
3  | 1          | 75       | 2018-02-07
4  | 2          | 200      | 2018-02-07
5  | 2          | 300      | 2018-02-09
```

The result I'm expecting is:
`(100-50) + (300-200) = 150`

One thing to keep in mind is that a bigger `ID` does not necessarily mean that it's the latest update as you can see in the example above.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Comment: naming your tables with reserved words is a bad idea)

Getting the smallest and largest values is trivial:

```
 SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(distance) - MIN(distance)
 FROM `updates`
 GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

Adding these values is trivial when you know that a SELECT query can be used n place of a table - but you also need to create aliases for the aggregated attributes:

```
 SELECT SUM(diff)
 FROM (
   SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(distance) - MIN(distance) AS diff
   FROM `updates`
   GROUP BY vehicle_id
 ) AS src
```